# ASP.NET- Send a Mail after clicking on a link in outlook mail using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, email

I am successfully sending an outlook mail from my c# application with the following html content.

MYForm:

form

{Role}, {Firstname} {lastname} with User ID {userID} has requested for the TurboComp access.

```
    <p><a href="yes">Yes,Grant the Access</a></p>
<p><a href="no">No,Acess Denied</a></p>
```

/form

Now, when the recipient receives the mail with this html content, and click on "yes" or "no" link, I want an outlook email to be sent back to the user who has initially sent the mail.

Thanks, In advance

Comment: Store a DB record indicating you sent a mail to X person, and return that ID from the email in the URL when they click yes or no.  Then you know for whom and the context, and can then grab that user's email and send the reply back.  Whatever you put in the email, as far as the URL goes, I would recommend encrypting.

Comment: There is a same article named "How do I create an HTML button that acts like a link?" in this site. Look at that if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to trigger the email back from outlook when the user clicks on link.
I made following change to my form:

MyForm:

form

{Role}, {Firstname} {lastname} with User ID {userID} has requested for the TurboComp access.

```
    <p><a href="http://localhost:localhostAddressonbrowser/Controller/ActionMethod">Yes,Grant the Access</a></p>

<p><a href="http://localhost:localhostAddressonbrowser/Controller/ActionMethod">No,Access Denied</a></p>
</form>
```

ThankYou:)

Answer (score 0):

this is my way to how to do if I were you.

You can generate the unique route for catching clicks in action.

Example : [Route("Foo/{memberId=0}/{canAccess}")]

Then you generate that URL yes and no buttons in your HTML content because the recipient will click it. You care of that URL. It has to contain memberId and button access state(yes or no) so when the recipient clicks the URL you can use your business below the route attribute like an example.

```
[Route("Foo/{memberId=0}/{canAccess}")]
public ActionResult Foo(string memberId, bool canAccess)
{
    // Code..
}
```

Hope this could help to you.